# MySQL specific update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table as follows. "url" fields that have the same record 4 random "st" area "1" I want to update it.
it is possible to do with sql query?

[image]

update the results will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: show the output you want

Comment: @splash58 I updated.

Comment: why does it change one row and not another? what's different about those rows that make you set them to a "1"?

Comment: Your "tsql" tag is wrong.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the OP wants the column `st` updated with a random value (either 0 or 1).
If this is true, the following statement will do:

```
update mytable set st=floor(rand()*2);
```

[`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> Returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0.

So `RAND()*2` gives a float `0 <= v < 2.0`, and `FLOOR()` strips off the fractional part giving 0 or 1.

This works because `floor(rand()*2)` is re-evaluated for every row, so each row gets a "new" random value. One *might* think, MySQL evaluates the RAND part only once (giving all columns the same value) but this is not the case.